# Are U-lock "wheel extenders" sold separately?

Tags: lock, security

I quite like the Kryptonite U-lock "wheel extender" idea - but I'm less attached to Kryptonite as a company - and even less so to the Messenger series of their locks, which is the only one that has this feature.

[image: Kryptonite Messenger Mini U Lock]

Are these wheel extenders available separately? I can't find them as a separate item on Kryptonite's website and don't see anyone else offering them either. Are they called generically something else?

Comment: I can't visualise how this would work.  D lock is to go around the rear wheel-rim and the seatpost?  Where does the extender go?   Or the D goes around stationary object and seat tube, and the wheel extender goes around the rear wheel?

Comment: Two variations: 1) frame+rear wheel with extender on parking post; 2) frame on parking post with extender to front wheel.  My ebike has a weird diamondless shape so I can't do a Sheldon to secure the rear wheel so it'd be frame to post with extender on the rear wheel, which has the $$$hub.

Comment: I've seen a chunky cable lock (the sort that expects a padlock to close, with an eyelet at each end) that worked for this purpose - essentially the D lock was the padlock.

Comment: Does your unusual frame prevent you from locking the rear wheel and (seat|chain) stays even with quite a large D-lock? The large lock would be a similar weight to this system, no harder to carry, and (as it would be full of bike) wouldn't give access for a car jack or similar attack.

Comment: It's more metal than you probably want to carry but 4-5 links of heavy duty security chain could do the job. But not many places cut it to length, and you'd need to check it fitted round the lock.

Comment: TBH, that just looks harder to use than a cable, plus has the side benefit of providing the thief with extra leverage to break the lock.

Comment: I'd just get a heavy-duty cable.

Comment: @RoboKaren - can you not cover these cases with a long shackle U-lock or a motorcycle lock?

Comment: it would be a great idea to sell WHEEL EXTENDER seprately. I think they can sell at 7pounds and give more protection than a simple Kryptoflex cable that thieves cut very easily.

Comment: This has picked up a close vote for being a product recommendation or similar. I disagree -- it's asking if a product exists, and we have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6):

Kryptonite does not sell that separately right now(source: am a Kryptonite distributor), but I'll bring it up to them, see if they are interested in offering it.